# What is the potential of herbalism?

Tags: adnd-2e, proficiency

In the AD&D 2e Player's Handbook a short description of herbalism is given - among other things it states that a character who possesses herbalism proficiency can make "non-magical potions, poultices, powders, balms, salves, ointments, infusions and plasters".

I was wondering if anybody knew what the effect of these concoctions might be - will salves and ointments have healing capabilities? And what makes a potion "magical" - what are the limitations of herbalism?

Answer (score 6):

Beyond the fact that the herbalism proficiency assists the healing proficiency, the PHB leaves the mechanical effects of the salves, ointments and poisons to the discretion of individual DMs.

I suggest you do a search on the web; there used to be netbooks compiled by fans for these sort of questions. In particular, we got the creator of the Forgotten Realms setting, Ed Greenwood (amongst others), providing data on the herbs of Faerun. You can see a few examples in the following thread on the Candlekeep forums: "[Herbs in the Realms](http://www.forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=19509)". I quote some of the effects mentioned on that thread here for quick access:

- > ... herbs that are nigh-irresistible (or in other cases abhorrent) to various races (orcs, dwarves, elves, gnomes, halflings), ...
- > ... herbs, potions, and even diets and thorras (“teas” or more properly tissanes made by boiling the leaves of various plants; a “thorra” is the Realmsian term for purely medical-use drinks that aren’t primarily sustaining or pleasant to the taste) used across the Realms to try to increase chances of, or “ensure,” pregnancy. ... one of the most popular effective ones is the ... Realmsian herb “halvalondur,”
- > Merenthe: ... potent sleep-inducing drug that can bring “easy slumber” regardless of pain or nausea. ... works very swiftly, and when “passing off” causes swift awakening with little or no drowsiness. ... The secrets of its making are widely-known in Calimshan, known to a few in the Vilhon, the Tashalar, Amn, and Waterdeep, and little known elsewhere (where prices are high; typically 60 to 80 gp for a standard-sized potion vial, which if entirely imbibed at one sitting by an average-sized adult human male will cause about 5-and-a-half days of slumber).
- > Sarsson: ... has a strong peppery, lemony taste, and can be used to make foul water palatable (not safe, just more pleasant in taste) and to complement meat; it “enlivens” uncoagulated blood on contact to bring forth a vivid, strong taste that some creatures (such as giant striders and certain carrion birds, like gorcraws) find irresistible.
- > Tanglemoss: ... its name is derived from its firm adherence to underlying rock or earth, and hence its usefulness, ... Dried tanglemoss is used as packing and insulation, because it doesn’t crumble and disintegrate for more than a season after death, but it has no other known uses.
- > Glowmoss: ... absorbs heat and light energy, and glows softly in dim or dark conditions. ... Owners of glowmoss who understand its needs can readily illuminate a dwelling or structure by moving clumps of glowmoss from interior ceiling “light cages” to sunlit outdoor “reviving” locations, and back again, ...

Magical potions are usually a lot more potent compared to these effects. Magical potion brewing is an entirely different process, requiring expensive materials and research time at a laboratory (or a specially consecrated altar) for wizards (or clerics) of at least 9th level. The details are provided in the *Dungeon Master Guide*.

---

Personal suggestion from our own gaming table: The sort of things that homemade remedies can resolve in our daily lives should be possible through the herbalism proficiency. Anything that requires modern science & medicine, tends to require magic in the gaming world.